# How to alter the value of variable with a function?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to alter the value of a variable with a function and store it permanently.
 tried the code below but it doesn't alter the value of variable.

```
n=2
def f(x):
    x+=2
    return x

f(n)
print n    #the output is 2 instead of 4 I want
```

Answer (score 2):

Think of variable as labels to values, `n` is labeling `2`, if you want n to label the value of the `f` function just label it again:

```
n=2
def f(x):
    x+=2
    return x
n = f(n)
print n
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(x):
    return x + 2

n = 2
n = f(n)
print(n)
```

This is how functions should be used. They receive values as arguments and return new values. When/where/how that is assigned to a variable is the caller's problem, since the variable is in the caller's scope.

If you want "self modification", a class is probably the better option:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def inc(self):
        self.n += 2


f = Foo(2)
f.inc()
print(f.n)
```